# How to reduce sinusoidal ripple output coming from SMPS?

Tags: dc, switch-mode-power-supply, filter, switching-regulator, ripple

I have an SMPS producing output of 12V,1Amps. It is giving a voltage ripple (I am not sure if ripple right term for this) as given in image.
[image]
I donot have permission to make any changes to this SMPS Circuit. I use this 12V as an input to a switching regulator that output 5VDC as given circuit below.

[image]

When I measure the 5V in oscilloscope it still shows the same ripple (about 4V pk-pk) as seen earlier in 12V input. This is causing microcontroller in my board unable to flash sometimes.

[image]
[image]

When this ripple is reduced to around 500mv pk-pk (This I do by disconnecting external load connected to SMPS) it flashes without issues. Please suggest some solutions that I can do on my regulator circuit shown above to nullify this even when load connected.

My circuit after regulator draws <250mA of current.
SMPS Frequency : 100kHz
Switching Regulator frequency: 60kHz
Oscilloscope images are taken with DC coupling.
Yes, surely there is issue with SMPS,but as I said, I donot have permission to alter anything in it.

I have tried to increase capacitance C66 from 470uF to 1000uF, But no use. I tried by adding various combination of low pass filters at output. Still not even a mm/mV drop in this ripple.

Comment: I think that's called ringing rather than ripple. Looks like it is 30MHz. You could try a ferrite bead. That seems like a serious problem with the SMPS itself though. It's supposed to be 5V but is slamming the output with 8V. Anything running off that actually needs that 5V is going to have trouble and no one is allowed to do anything about it?

Comment: As DKNguynen said, at 30MHz ferrite beads on your 12v line could help. Also, note that electrolytics dont have much use at those frequencies. Ceramic and PP film caps are useful. You can also try putting a 0.1uF ceramic cap very close to the chip being flashed. And a ceramic or pp film cap at your 12 v input after the ferrite bead.  It looks like the 12v supply is automotive grade. Not really a clean output.

Comment: Show us where you're picking off the ground and 5V from the circuit.  If the ground wire from the cold end of C67 to the ground of your microprocessor has current from the 12V SMPS circuit flowing in it, then your problem isn't a dirty 12V supply -- it's a dirty ground, from ground bounce.

Comment: If the scope probe is near the inductor or the loop where high switching currents occur, it might also couple capacitively or magnetically to the probe. Use the ground spring on the probe, the crocodile clip lead is useless at these frequencies.

Comment: @DKNguyen : Thanks for the hint, I only had normal inductors with me. I have placed order for ferrite bead 
NFZ15SF102SZ10D and it should reach me in 1week. Will update you after testing it.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop : Thanks for the help. I did try with ceramic capacitors as you mentioned, but not with ferrite beads. Will try soon

Comment: @DKNguyen : It took a while to procure ferrite beads. Now I tried using ferrite beads of 120E,600E,1000E at 100MHz spec. But all 3 were of no use. I used them before and after 12V & 5V terminals in above circuit diagram individually respectively.

Comment: Ferrite beads were the easy solution if they worked. You need to be aware of the way ferrite bead currents are rated and impedance curves because you can easily saturate them if you don't understand. I don't buy ferrite beads without curves. I would say read "Ferrite beads demystified" but some genuis at analog devices decided apparently you now need to make an account to read their articles. Bypass that with PDSF version AN-1368.

Comment: If that still doesn't work then you might need a second  order output filter with damping: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/designing-second-stage-output-filters-for-switching-power-supplies.html

Comment: @DKNguyen : Finally 1000E at 100MHz bead and a paraller 10ohm resistor did the job!! (The filter circuit I implemented from the link you shared - https://imgur.com/a/Q0X8bQo ) Although ringing was still there, but strangely it didnot cause programming/debugging issue with my controller.

Comment: @VishweshGM What worked? It is unclear. You built a damping circuit with the ferrite bead? If so, just note the last paragraph before the Conclusion section.

Comment: @DKNguyen : I added 10ohm resistor in parallel to L5 inductor(referring to circuit in the question, L5 replaced with ferrite bead) which solved the issue of "Not flashing with load". Last paragraph, I understand it is not recommended method. But for my application it seems tobe working.Unfortunately I am not good/expert enough to analyze why it is working from theoretical perspective.